# AngularJS: Angular UI Router load multiple templates for testing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-runner, angular-template

I'm trying to perform a simple test on a helper function I've created:

```
    function getPostId() {
        return $stateParams._id;
    }
```

And here is the test I am using, please note that getService is simply a wrapper for the Angular `inject()` function:

```
describe('wpApp Router', function() {

    var $state, $stateParams, Router;

    beforeEach(module('wpApp.core.router'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        $state = getService('$state');
        $scope = getService('$rootScope');
        $stateParams = getService('$stateParams');
        Router = getService('Router');
        $templateCache = getService('$templateCache');

        $templateCache.put('/app/sections/posts/list/post-list.html', '');
    });

    it('should provide the current post ID', function() {
        $state.go('posts.details', { _id: 1 });
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(Router.getPostId()).to.equal(1);
    });
});
```

My router looks like this:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts',
            controller: 'PostsListController as postsList',
            templateUrl: '/app/sections/posts/list/post-list.html'
        })

        .state('posts.details', {
            url: '/:_id',
            controller: 'PostDetailsController as postDetails',
            templateUrl: '/app/sections/posts/details/post-details.html'
        })
```

I'm trying to set the current state to `posts.details` with an `_id` of 1. Then test my helper function to see if it is correctly retrieving the ID.

However, I am getting errors with the templates of the states, like the following: `Unexpected request: GET /app/sections/posts/details/post-details.html`

The state `posts.details` is a child of `posts` and both have their own templates, the problem is I am unable to load both into the `templateCache` or at least I can't figure out how to do so.

Is it possible to load both templates in order to fulfill the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your actual question, the easiest approach to caching templates is by using something like [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor). It will cache all your application templates, and make them available to your tests as a module.

However, from what I can surmise from the code provided, this is un-necessary. Currently, your unit test is actually an integration test in that it's dependent on the routing of the `'posts.details'` state in order to pass, and yet the method itself is concerned only with the `$stateParams` object.

So, instead, as `$stateParams` is in fact just a plain object, a simpler (and better) approach is just to mock it prior to your test:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('$stateParams', {
    _id: 1
  });
}));
```

and then you can test your service method in isolation from your states:

```
it('should provide the current post ID', function() {
   expect(Router.getPostId()).toEqual(1);
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting started with testing, so this post is much more helpful than if you sent me the just first response. :)